# ImpersonatedLoggedOnUser and LogonUser does not work properly

Tags: c++, visual-c++, impersonation

I am working around impersonating in c++ for days.

I found many sources such as :

Microsoft Impersonation Example [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CppImpersonateUser-a0fbfd54)

Impersonation for reading files in code project [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21050/Security-User-Impersonation) **it`s not works in my compter and show me access denied**

And many forums and blogs which discuss about impersonating in stackoverflow and others, which none of them work in my computer(windows 2016) ( the above links impersonate and show me that impersonation is successful but i add a code to get directory list or read a file or create a file which is returns failed because of permission) . I used those links and understand that impersonating in local system can be done by using 
**LogonUser** and **ImpersonatedLoggedOnUser** and **RevertToSelf** functions. I create a test project in c++ console by using these functions. they work and return true when I pass right parameters but i cannot access to logon user profile.

I have 2 users in my computer which is not joined to any domain:

1. Administrator
2. Test3

I run below code in user Test3, and try to get file size in Administrator`s Desktop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
void get_file_size(std::string path)
{
    truct _stat fileinfo;
    _stat(path.c_str(), &fileinfo);
    std::cout<<"file size is " << fileinfo.st_size;
}
int main()
{
    HANDLE  tokenHandle;
    bool returnValue = LogonUser(L"Administrator", L"", L"*******", LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &tokenHandle);
    if (false == returnValue) {
        return -1;
    }
    bool res = ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(tokenHandle);
    if (res)
    {
        std::string path = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\1.txt";
        get_file_size(path);
        RevertToSelf();
    }
    CloseHandle(tokenHandle);
    return 0;
}
```

Also I try other ways of impersonating such as **CreateThread, OpenProcess or Changing Impersonation Level** and other recommended Microsoft API functions which their codes available on internet, they don`t work again.

At the first i want to know why this code is wrong
Second I want to create a context which make me able to do whatever I want by other user permission.